# "TypeError: Failed to fetch" when making a GET request from SwaggerHub

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following API definition in SwaggerHub:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: defaultDescription
  version: '0.1'
  title: defaultTitle
host: swapi.co
paths:
  /api/people:
    get:
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: search
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          x-example: luke
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Definition generated from Swagger Inspector
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Model0'
          responseSchema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Model0'
definitions:
  Results:
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      height:
        type: string
      mass:
        type: string
      hair_color:
        type: string
      skin_color:
        type: string
      eye_color:
        type: string
      birth_year:
        type: string
      gender:
        type: string
      homeworld:
        type: string
      films:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      species:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      vehicles:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      starships:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      created:
        type: string
      edited:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
  Model0:
    properties:
      count:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      next:
        type: object
      previous:
        type: object
      results:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Results'
```

I cannot make this basic GET command to bring back the data I'm seeking. It only returns this:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

I'm unsure if it's a syntax issue, or possibly spacing, but I'm also getting an error for line 19 that reads:

> should NOT have additional properties
>   additionalProperty: responseSchema, description, schema

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What tool do you use to make the API calls? Swagger Editor/Swagger UI?

Comment: I'm using both through SwaggerHub. It's a split display.

Answer (score 1):

https://swapi.co seems to be HTTPS-only, so you need to add

```
schemes:
  - https
```

to you API definition to specify the protocol for requests.

> but I'm also getting an error for line 19 that reads: "should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: responseSchema, description, schema".

Remove these lines:

```
          responseSchema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Model0'
```

There's no `responseSchema` keyword in OpenAPI.